# How to calculate the currents of \$I_R\$,\$I_L\$ and \$I_C\$?

Tags: circuit-analysis

How are you? I am working in the next circuit, so \$I_R\$,\$I_L\$ and \$I_C\$ 
can be calculated.

---

[image: Circuit]

---

The next data is supplied

- \$R=?\$
- \$L=4.3mH\$
- \$C=220 μF\$
- \$i(t)=15u_1(t)A\$
- \$M_p\leq16.3\%\$
- \$t_s\pm2\%\$ \$=10ms\$

The first thing done is calculate the model of the system, and I just used the inductor current, but it can be in terms the current in the resistance or the capacitor too, the coefficients must be the same:
$$\frac{d^2I_L}{dt^2}+\frac{1}{RC}\frac{dI_L}{dt}+\frac{1}{CL}I_L=\frac{1}{CL}i(t)$$
The next pass is about taking the parameters like the natural frecuency, damping ratio, gain; for this system:

$$\alpha=\epsilon\omega_n$$
$$2\alpha=\frac{1}{RC}$$
$$\alpha=\frac{1}{2RC}..[1]$$
$$\omega_n^2=\frac{1}{LC}$$
$$\omega_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt(LC)}..[2]$$
comparing [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6KPq.png) and [2]
$$\epsilon=\frac{\sqrt(L)}{2R\sqrt(C)}..[3]$$
Next try to calculate \$\epsilon\$, R and the  \$\epsilon@16.3\%\$
 - From the overdamping case
$$\epsilon>1$$ then $$\frac{\sqrt(L)}{2R\sqrt(C)}>1$$ or $$\frac{\sqrt(L)}{2\sqrt(C)}>R$$
then \$t_s@2\%\$ \$=\frac{4}{\epsilon\omega_n}\$ (I dont remember is this numerator is 3 or 4), so $$\epsilon=\frac{4}{(10\times10^-3)(\frac{1}{\sqrt(LC)})}=0.389$$. On tho R, comparing terms 
$$0.389\frac{1}{\sqrt((4.3\times10^-3)(220\times10^-6))}$$$$=\frac{1}{2RC}$$
 From here, R is 
$$\frac{1}{2(220\times10^-6)(400)}=568$$
$$\epsilon$$ of the 16.3%, ergh, say, the overpass at 16.3% is calculated from the definition $$M_p=e^{(\frac{-\epsilon\pi}{\sqrt(1-\epsilon^2)})}$$
$$Ln0.163=\frac{-\epsilon\pi}{\sqrt(1-\epsilon^2)}$$
and $$\epsilon_{16.3\%}=0.50$$

and using KCL
$$I(t)=I_{R_1}+I_{L_1}+I_{C_1}$$
But isnt clear how the parameters calculated are related to the currents. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "15u1(t)A" mean? What is "Mp"? What does "Ts@2%" mean?

Comment: \$u_1(t)\$, means the [unit step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), \$M_p\$ its the value of the first peak of the system and \$T_s\pm2\%\$ is the time to reach and stay within 2% of the response

Comment: So current starts at 0 and goes to 15A at t=0, correct? "first peak of the system" is what, peak voltage? "But isnt clear how the parameters calculated are related to the currents" - once you know the values of all the components you should be able to calculate the currents passing through them at any time. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for your interest Bruce, Its not peak voltage is the peak of the step response of the system like the one showed at right [step response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_response), the current is right.

Comment: But does the "peak of the step response" coincide with peak output voltage, or is it something else?  I read further and found that 'M' represents the set of states in a dynamical system. So what does "Mp <=16%" mean?

Comment: \$M_p<=16{\%}\$ its the max deviation that reach the step response of the system compared to the steady state value. I.e. How much is the diference between the final value and the peak value. I dont think it does necessary the peak voltage and the peak response are the same.

Comment: Do you have to do this in the time domain?  Would you be ok if it was done in the Laplace domain?

Comment: Both ways are fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> R=? L=4.3mH C=220μF i(t)=15u1(t)A Mp≤16.3% ts±2%
>    =10ms

My analysis as follows;

- Using \$Q=X(f_0)/R= \frac{1}{2\zeta}\$ at resonant \$f_0\$
- Mp=overshoot % 16.3% and from chart below  \$\zeta=0.35, \text { then } Q=1.4 \$
- \$f_0=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}=140Hz \$
- thus \$R=Q*Z_L(140 Hz)= 1 * 2\pi 140[Hz]*4.3[mH]= 3.8 \text{ }  \Omega =R \$

Initial condition \$Ic(0)=15A,  I_L(0)=0A... I_R(0)=0 . . .                    V_R(0)=0V\$

Final condition \$Ic=0A,  I_L=15A. . . I_R=0 . . .V_R=0 \$

[image]

- Response can be show from normalized for Q=1
- Ts is redundant